# Create a faceted search for custom javascript items using Views

Tags: drupal, view

Hi
I am trying to create a faceted search using Views. I have created several taxonomy terms for some custom javascript content nodes & want to give a visitor the flexibility to search through those nodes using those taxonomy terms.

I cannot us the faceted search module because my host does not allow me to install modules.
I know it can be created using Views, but I am simply unable to implement it.

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the taxonomy term filter, then "Expose" it, this will create a drop down menu for the user to search from.

It will probably take a lot of twiddling to get to work like faceted search (You may need to manually add the "Search box" as a header on the views page and direct it to itsself via a views argument)